# how to show icon on action bar in android

Tags: android

I want to implement action bar in my application i write some code in activity and add xml file .
but icon on action bar is not show . I try much but i cant know
 that what is wrong with this code

Java code is here:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.testmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /*public boolean onOptionsItemSelected1(MenuItem item)

            {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.register:
            finish();

        }
        return true;
    }
*/
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    /*    int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

        }
      */  
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.register:
            finish();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
  //      return super.onOptionsItemSelected1(item);
    }
```

and xml code is

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item 

      android:id="@+id/register"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
     android:showAsAction="alway"
      android:orderInCategory="100"
      android:icon="@drawable/register"

      />  

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your testmenu.xml

```
android:showAsAction="alway"
```

change to:

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

Comment: I also try this but till not appearing any icon on action bar

Answer (score 0):

```
 android:showAsAction="alway"
```

*alway* **->** *always*

**UPDATE**

try this

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/register"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        myapp:showAsAction="always"
        android:visible="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/register" />
</menu>
```

Comment: I also try this but till not appearing any icon on action bar .

Comment: @MuhammadSohailiqbal I updated my answer, may be problem in your order number